# Создание собственных событий

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, события

Скажите пожалуйста, как создать создать событие? Если по точнее, то у меня есть класс в котором лежит поток, который выполняет циклическую (`while(true)`) работу, ну например `sleep 1000` и вот как мне прикрепить например метод "void Check(тут параметры передаваемые от события)" из основного файла activity на тот момент когда проходит `sleep 1000` в потоке из другого класса?

Comment: Это называется [колбэк-интерфейс](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2015/10/callback-android.html?m=1) (метод обратного вызова)

Comment: можно воспользоваться, на мой взгляд паттерном слушатель, который в java уже реализован